# How to write wrapper function for axios requests?

Tags: javascript

Let's see an example:

What I'd like to do:

```
const authEndpoints = ["/login", "/register"];

const checkRequest = request => {
  const { url, data } = request;

  return authEndpoints.includes(url)
    ? {...request, data: {...data, auth: true}}
    : request
}
```

so calling

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/login',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams'
  }
});
```

would end up in:

```
{
  method: 'post',
  url: '/login',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams',
    auth: true
  }
}
```

but

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/sendmsg',
  data: {
    msg: "Hello"
  }
});
```

would end up as it is now.

Is there a way for axios to process requests before being sent? I was trying `axios.interceptors.request.use`, but doesn't seem like it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Axios [Interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

```
const authEndpoints = ["/login", "/register"];

const http = axios.create({
  auth: false
})

http.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.auth = authEndpoints.includes(config.url)
  return config;
});
```

Then call the request on`http` instead of `axios`

```
http({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/login',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an axios instance with your custom config first.
[Create an instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance)

Answer (score 1):

Interceptors should do the trick in your case:

```
const authEndpoints = ["/login", "/register"];

const config = { 
  //your default config for all requests
}

const http = axios.create(config);

http.interceptors.request.use((request) => {

  return {...request, data: {...data, auth: authEndpoints.include(request.url)}}
});
```

Then you can use it like

```
http.get(...)
//
http.post(...)
```

Note that creating new axios instance is needed there. That's why maybe it did not work for you?